# How to deploy code using git

Tags: git

I have a bare repository initialize on my webserver.
I code on my workstation and I'm able to push/pull/commit changes to it.
Now, I want to deploy this code on the webserver but into my apache directory (/var/www/html).
If I wanted to track the changes (only pull no push) from this directory, should I clone the repo first?

This way I can make changes locally, then commit and push to "central repo" and then pull from the documentroot folder to see the changes in "prod."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using git clone and then pulling changes from the repo.

Answer (score 4):

I think the keyword you're looking for is "continuous integration". There are tons that are geared for SVN but GIT is new so it's slowly rolling out. I use CruiseControl.NET for my .NET projects and it's a dream!

I don't know the technology your projects are in but for GIT Hudson comes to mind. Link to Hudson GIT plugin: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin

Good Luck!
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without mucking with Ruby on Rails or just want to keep it simple, I suggest checking out http://more.zites.net/git_deploy_code_changes

I'm running into the same thing as you and this worked for me best.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) - combined with SSH keys it's a wonderful lightweight solution for easy deployment.

I blend this with [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/) to deploy dev builds to stage & release builds to production in a well organized/controlled way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out what I learned here about securely deploying a git project to a remote webserver without exposing your repo to your webserver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941021/470749

I found it more lightweight to set up than something like Hudson or Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

git is not quite suitable for deployment. I suggest writing your own deployment scripts, or using a tool like capistrano.

Answer (score -1):

See: http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano