# How to deploy from git repo without server having access to repo?

Tags: git, deployment, rsync, scp

I have a PHP project in a BitBucket git repo.

I work in a branch called "develop" for small fixes, or I work in temporary feature branches.  When I'm ready to deploy, I merge those branches into "master".

I want to make deploying to my live site as easy as that (merging to master and pushing to BitBucket).

**But I really don't want my server to have any access to my repo because that adds security concerns.**  If you care about security, you want your repo to be in as few places as possible.  If your server gets compromised, that's a bad enough situation, but it would be even worse if the attacker then would have access to my full repo.  [This person](http://blogs.collab.net/cloudforge/publish-code-ftp-scp-rsync-over-ssh) agrees.

So I assume that I'll want to use something like `git archive master`, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/163769/470749 explains.

How can I set up a hook that detects a push of "master" and then runs `git archive master` to export the latest code (not as a repo, though) to a compressed zip file which it then sends (via SCP and/or Rsync?) to the remote server, unzips it to a new directory, and then (maybe via changing a symlink) points the server to that new directory?

Bonus question: how could I enable easy emergency rollbacks? (I imagine there might be situations where I want to revert to the previous commit quickly.)

Comment: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy with the scripts I ended up with:

**deploy.sh:**

```
##This executable file will export your latest code from master (via "git archive") and will upload it 
##to the remote server and then call a script on the server to handle from there.
##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

source dev-ops/archive_and_upload.sh

##On the remote server, run a script to archive the existing production site files and then deploy the uploaded package.
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myUserName@vientiane.dreamhost.com <<'ENDSSH'

set -e

cd /home/myUserName/myProjectName/latest

##Unzip the zip file, then delete it.
echo "Unzipping the package.zip..."
unzip -o package.zip && rm package.zip  

cd /home/myUserName/myProjectName/

nowTime=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%d__%H:%M:%S")
echo "The archive will have this timestamp: " $nowTime

##Copy the "latest" folder to a dated "packages" subfolder.
cp -R latest/ packages/$nowTime 
echo "Copied the existing site to an archive."

##Install Laravel dependencies.
echo "Running Composer so that the remote server downloads and installs dependencies..."
cd packages/$nowTime 
php -d memory_limit=256M ~/bin/composer.phar install   

##Delete the "live" symlink and immediately create a new "live" symlink to the most recent subfolder within "packages".
echo "Updating the symlinks..."
cd /home/myUserName/myProjectName/
echo `pwd`
rm previous
mv live previous && ln -s packages/$nowTime live && ls -lah  

##Clear out the "latest" folder in preparation for next time.
echo "Deleting the contents of the 'latest' folder in preparation for next time..."
rm -rf latest/* && ls latest   
ENDSSH

echo "FINISHED DEPLOYING!"
```

**archive_and_upload.sh:**

```
##This executable file will export your latest code from master (via "git archive") and will upload it 
##to the remote server.
##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

##Clear out the contents of the previous export package.
rm -rf dev-ops/package/*   

##Export the "master" branch of this git repo. (The result is not a repo but is just code.)
git archive --format zip --output dev-ops/package/package.zip master  

##Send zip file to remote server.
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa dev-ops/package/package.zip myUserName@vientiane.dreamhost.com:/home/myUserName/myProjectName/latest/package.zip
```

**revert_to_previous_package.sh:**

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myUserName@vientiane.dreamhost.com <<'ENDSSH'

set -e

cd /home/myUserName/myProjectName/

mv live rollingBack && mv previous live && mv rollingBack previous && ls -lah

ENDSSH

echo "ROLLED BACK!"
```

As you can see, I set my Dreamhost server to serve from a folder called "live", which is really just a symlink to a subfolder that is named as the timestamp for when that package of code was uploaded.  There is also another symlink called "previous" which makes rolling back easy (in case I notice problems after deploying and want to revert).